# bind sql database table to a silver light datagrid

Tags: silverlight

how to bind sql database table to  a silver light datagrid with out using linq?

how can that be done?

Comment: Why do you not want to use LINQ? Presumably then, you have a class that represents your DB table?

Comment: You could use RIA with a custom DomainService to provide your objects, but why do you not want to use LINQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not bind sql datatable to silverlight datatable directly.

I did it like :

1) I have created business object in webservice :

```
Public Structure DCDData
        Dim ProductDescription As String
        Dim Yield As String
        Dim Pair As String
        Dim Tenor As String
        Dim StrikePoints As String
End Structure
```

2) Writtern webservice method which is returning List of business object

```
 Dim list As New List(Of DCDData)
 Dim dtTable As New DataTable("DataTable1")
```

Call objDCD_Product_Dashboard_DB_Functions.DB_Get_DCDData(strCcyPair, strTenor, dtTable)

For i As Integer = 0 To dtTable.Rows.Count - 1
     Dim objDcdData As New DCDData
     objDcdData.ProductDescription = dtTable.Rows(i).Item("Product_Description").ToString
     objDcdData.Yield = dtTable.Rows(i).Item("Yield").ToString
     objDcdData.Pair = dtTable.Rows(i).Item("Pair").ToString
     objDcdData.Tenor = dtTable.Rows(i).Item("Tenor").ToString
     objDcdData.StrikePoints = dtTable.Rows(i).Item("Strike Points").ToString
     list.Add(objDcdData)
 Next

Return list

3) In silverlight page Bind datagrid to List of object